# Opel Corsa 1.7 DTI -2009

Tags: starting, opel, corsa

The spanner light flashes... when I tried starting the vehicle it starts for a second or 2 then switches off. I disconnected the battery terminals and reconnected them after 30 minutes. problem still them

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! have you checked to see if there are any codes stored in the ECM? Usually when a car starts for 2 seconds and quits, I think there might be an issue with the security system, as in the ECM has dropped the key and now won't let it start. It might also be the fuel pump, but don't go changing anything before you figure it out for sure.

Comment: Perhaps related: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/51295/engine-firing-up-but-dying-immediately

I'd lend a known good battery from a friend or second car and test it again.